# Logic grid puzzle - Carson City Chronicle

Tags: logical-deduction, logic-grid

I can't figure this one out. Any help would be appreciated.

Journalist-in-training Janet Seymour's byline appeared in the *Carson City Chronicle* on six days last week. On each day (Monday through Saturday), she published a story under a different headline, each of which was based on a different number of interviews (one, three, four, six, seven, or eight). Her editor added a different type of visual aid (including a caricature) to each story. Can you determine the day that the story with each headline was published, as well as the number of interviews Janet did for each story and the visual aid that accompanied it?

1. Janet conducted 1 more interview for the story accompanied by the bar graph than she did for the "biotech firm patents seeds" story
2. Neither the diagram nor the map accompanied the story headlined "sunny days for jazz festival"
3. Janet conducted 1 more interview for the "millworkers win raise" story than she did for the one accompanied by the map
4. The story for which she conducted 4 interviews appeared the day after the "airport expansion" story but the day before the story accompanied by the photograph
5. Janet conducted 2 more interviews for the story containing the diagram than she did for the story headlined "stockcar race"
6. Neither "millworkers win raise" nor "german diplomat" is the story containing the bar graph (which wasn't published on Thursday)
7. The story for which Janet conducted 8 interviews appeared the day after "sunny days"
8. The story headlined "german diplomat" appeared the day before the one accompanied by the diagram
9. The pie chart didn't accompany the story for which she conducted 3 interviews
10. The story accompanied by the bar graph appeared the day before the one for which Janet conducted 1 interview

By Georgena S. Sil

Logic Lover's Logic Problems June 2015

[link to an online solver](http://jsingler.de/apps/logikloeser/#(at:s,items:!(!(AIRPORT,BIOTECH,GERMAN,MILLWORKERS,STOCKCAR,SUNNY),!(MONDAY,TUESDAY,WEDNESDAY,THURSDAY,FRIDAY,SATURDAY),!(%27BAR%20GRAPH%27,CARICATURE,DIAGRAM,MAP,PHOTOGRAPH,%27PIE%20CHART%27),!(ONE,THREE,FOUR,SIX,SEVEN,EIGHT)),ms:t,n:!(a0b4,a0b5,a2b5,a5b5,b0d0,b0d2,b0d5,b5d2,b3c0,b5c0,b0c2,b0c4,b1c4,a1c0,a3c0,a2c0,c0d0,c0d1,c0d3,a2c2,a4c2,a5c2,c2d0,c2d2,c2d4,a3c3,a5c3,c3d0,c3d2,c3d5,c4d2,c5d1,a0c4,a1d0,a3d0,a3d1,a4d1,a0d2,a1d2,a3d3,a4d4,a5d5,a4d5,a1d5),nc:4,ni:6,p:!(),v:0))

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil Personally I would prefer a dedicated tool like [this one](http://jsingler.de/apps/logikloeser/#(at:s,items:!(!('','','','','',''),!('','','','','',''),!('','','','','',''),!('','','','','','')),ms:t,n:!(),nc:4,ni:6,p:!(),v:0)). You can pre-fill it and then post the URL so that anyone can go on solving from the pre-fill point. Jay, such an external link is OK because, as long as the clues are written in the question, solving the puzzle does not depend on this external page (it just makes things easier for you and us)

Comment: @xhienne yeah smth which can be used a bit more easily that the table formatting here :P That's a useful link, I'll keep that in mind for future

Comment: I updated the post.. and i filled in everything i was able to on the graph. any help would be awesome!! thanks in advance everyone

Comment: This appears to be a variant of the famous Einstein's Riddle: https://ed.ted.com/lessons/can-you-solve-einstein-s-riddle-dan-van-der-vieren

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The important thing to keep in mind here is that

> Even though the grid is useful, you lose some important information with just the surface reading. In particular, we need to reanalyse the chronology (events which occur on consecutive days)

Chronology

> Each point represents events which occur on consecutive days (note that I've highlighted items that go together with **bold** or *italics*):
>  - **Airport**, 4, *Photograph*
>  - **Sunny**, 8
>  - **German**, *Diagram*
>  - *Bar Graph*, 1
>  Notice, in particular, that because Airport, Sunny and German cannot overlap, "Diagram" cannot go with 4 or 8 interviews.
>  Also, because Photograph and Diagram may not overlap, German cannot go together with 4 interviews.
>  Finally, because 1, 4 and 8 may not overlap, neither Airport or Sunny can go with Bar Graph (this automatically leads us to connecting Stockcar with Bar Graph and 4 interviews).

Number of interviews

> Now we can use the comparative number of interviews to our advantage:
>  - *Bar Graph* = **Biotech** + 1 (this means Biotech has 3 interviews)
>  - *Diagram* = **Stockcar** + 2 (this means Diagram has 6 interviews)
>  From here, we get more (Diagram connects to Airport, Mill connects to 8) and using the other information for comparative interviews:
>  - **Mill** = *Map* + 1
>  we find that Map is connected to 7 interviews (and German) and Sunny is connected to 1 interview. This means that we have completely connected number of interviews to events.

Back to chronology

> Now, we can use the previous discoveries to build up a longer sequence of consecutive days
>  - (**German**, 7, *Map*), (**Airport**, 6, *Diagram*), (**Stockcar**, 4, *Bar Graph*), (**Sunny**, 1, *Photograph*), (**Mill**, 8)
>  In particular (**Stockcar**, 4, *Bar Graph*) must occur on Wednesday or Thursday and since it cannot be Thursday, it must be Wednesday. This forces the events of the other days and allows us to finish.

Final solution

> [image]

Comment: you are amazing thank you for the break down and explanation!

Comment: If this post answered your question, please Accept it by clicking on the checkmark underneath the voting arrows (to the left of the top). That marks this problem as solved.